# AngularJS debugging in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS Controller I got

```
        var test = {
            "type": "pie",
            "theme": "light",
            "data": dataWantedArea,
            "valueField": "value",
            "titleField": "name",
            "balloon": {
                "fixedPosition": true
            },
            "autoMargins": false,
            "marginLeft": 5,
            "marginRight": 5,
            "marginBottom": 5,
            "marginTop": 5,
            "pullOutRadius": 0,
            colors: ["#36CB1F", "#F58426", "#F53E26"],
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        };
```

in my template I do

```
<am-chart ng-if="test.data.length" id="test" options="test" width="90vw" height="325px"></am-chart>
```

> Problem: its never shown, obviously test.data.length is ALWAYS false - so I would like to print some debugging in my template, is that possible somehow?
>   Of course If you know a direct solution to my problem, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug your code there is a cool browser plugin available.

http://ng-inspector.org/

There you can see a tree and all your values. It's very helpful to debug your code. You can see your scope and you can find and see problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use data or variable from controller to html, you have to use [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Use `$scope.test` intead of `var test`